# What does the ! character do in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, addressing-mode

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun();
int main()
{
        int a = 10;
        fun();
        return 0;

}
void fun()
{
    int a =  5;
}
```

Assembly code.

```
000103e4 <main>:
   103e4:       e52db008        str     fp, [sp, #-8]!
   103e8:       e58de004        str     lr, [sp, #4]
   103ec:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
   103f0:       e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
   103f4:       e3a0300a        mov     r3, #10
   103f8:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
   103fc:       eb000005        bl      10418 <fun>
   10400:       e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
   10404:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   10408:       e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
   1040c:       e59db000        ldr     fp, [sp]
   10410:       e28dd004        add     sp, sp, #4
   10414:       e49df004        pop     {pc}            ; (ldr pc, [sp], #4)

00010418 <fun>:
   10418:       e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   1041c:       e28db000        add     fp, sp, #0
   10420:       e24dd00c        sub     sp, sp, #12
   10424:       e3a03005        mov     r3, #5
   10428:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
   1042c:       e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
   10430:       e24bd000        sub     sp, fp, #0
   10434:       e49db004        pop     {fp}            ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
   10438:       e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

In a above assembly code 
103e4:       e52db008        str     fp, [sp, #-8]!

I am new to assembly language.
why '!' has been used what is the purpose.

Comment: infocenter.arm.com has arms documentation which includes details about the instruction set.

Comment: If you compile with optimizations (e.g. `-O2` for GCC), the generated assembly code will become much shorter and more readable. Without optimizations, a lot of "dummy" code is generated. Also, since this is probably C, declare and define functions as `void fun(void)` to make explicit that no parameters are passed.

Answer (score 6):

That `!` in ARM assembly code means the address register is updated. (It is very exciting!) In `str fp, [sp, #-8]!`, −8 is added to `sp`, and then the contents of `fp` are stored at the new address in `sp`. If the `!` were not present, `fp` would still be stored at the same address, but `sp` would not be updated.

There is a corresponding instruction which you see elsewhere in the code, `ldr fp, [sp], #4`. In this form, the contents of `fp` are stored at the address in `sp`, and then 4 is added to `sp`.

The first form is commonly used for pushing things onto the stack: The stack pointer is decremented to make room for new things on the stack, and then the value is written. The second form is used for popping: The value on the stack is read, and then the stack pointer is incremented, effectively removing the space from the live part of the stack.

They can also be used to iterate through an array, loading or storing elements and moving the pointer without needing separate instructions for loading/storing and changing the pointer.